# Problem of Conway - Singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question**. Let $f$ analytic in $G=\{z: 0<|z-a|<r\}$ except that there is a sequence of pole $(a_n)$ in $G$ with $a_n\rightarrow a$. Show that for any $w$ in $\mathbb{C}$ there is a sequence $(z_n)$ in $G$ with $a=\lim z_n$ and $w=\lim f(z_n)$.

My idea would be to find a $(z_n)$ sequence within each disc $D(a_n,\epsilon)$. This sequence converge to $a$. Hence f it is not defined in the $a$ then convergeria for a $w\in \mathbb{C}$ any.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=0$. The poles of $f(z)$ are not isolated around $z=0$, so $f(z)$ isn't meromorphic there.

If there is no such sequence $f(z_n)\to w, z_n \to 0$, then there is $\epsilon>0,\delta>0$ such that $|f(z)-w| > \epsilon$ on $U = \{|z| < \delta\}$.

Also, $f(z)-w$ has no zeros on $U$, and the poles of $f(z)-w$ become zeros of $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)-w}$,

so that $g(z)$ is holomorphic on $U \setminus \{0\}$. But it is also bounded by $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ there, which means that $z=0$ is a [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem), and $g(z)$ is holomorphic on $U$.

Thus $f(z)= w+\frac{1}{g(z)}$ is meromorphic on $U$, a contradiction.

Comment: I do not understand about meromorphic functions. The Conway book does not talk about meromorphism. What means? 
My idea is not correct?

Comment: Why the poles of $ f (z) -w $ are the zeros of $ g (z) $? Also I did not understand why $ z = $ 0 is a sing. isolated.

Comment: @LucianoGauss And I'm sure Conway defined "$h(z)$ is meromorphic " which means that $h(z) = \frac{h_2(z)}{h_3(z)}$ where $h_2,h_3$ are holomorphic. In the same way that the zeros of holomorphic functions are isolated,  the poles and the zeros of meromorphic functions are isolated, so your function $f(z)$ isn't meromorphic around $z=a$ (where its poles accumulate)

Comment: @LucianoGauss By definition, If $h(z)$ has a pole at $z=c$ then $\frac{1}{h(z)}$ is holomorphic and has a zero at $z=c$

Comment: In the case of the function $f$ at the end of the question, it is meromorphic because $g (z)$ is holomorphic and so its inverse is a quotient of functions holomorphic?

Comment: @LucianoGauss  yes, this is the point of considering the meromorphic functions, that they are closed by sum product **and** quotient

Comment: I can make function $g (z) = h (z) -a $ to generalize to the point $z = a$?

Comment: @LucianoGauss Come on..  Try by yourself, see if it works.

Comment: Rsrsrs... Ok, ok! Thank you for your help. See you.